# jquery animate setting the last value to all the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create an animation which looks like a stack of images and the user can scroll up and down as per his wish. My  problem is that after scrolling up my function which is **animationUp** is setting the last scale value to all the elements while debugging I saw that somehow it gets called twice. Please help!

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
        <li class="image-container">
            <img src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/2e/71/0f/2e710fc0-54c2-ce6a-3ce6-296cc0fe526e/icon175x175.png" alt="Receipt" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content ul li.image-container {
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     transform-origin: center top;
     text-align: center;
     margin-left: 50px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container img {
     max-width: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;
 }
 ul li.image-container:last-child img {
     transform: scale(1.2);
     margin-top: 700px;
 }
ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(2) img {
     transform: scale(1.1);
     margin-top: 200px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(3) img {
     transform: scale(1);
     margin-top: 100px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(4) img {
     transform: scale(0.9);
     margin-top: 50px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(5) img {
     transform: scale(0.8);
     margin-top: 1px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(6) img {
     transform: scale(0.7);
     margin-top: -40px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(7) img {
     transform: scale(0.6);
     margin-top: -80px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(8) img {
     transform: scale(0.55);
     margin-top: -100px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(9) img {
     transform: scale(0.5);
     margin-top: -120px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(10) img {
     transform: scale(0.45);
     margin-top: -140px;
 }
.content ul li.image-container:nth-last-child(n+10) img {
     transform: scale(0.4);
     margin-top: -155px;
 }
```

**JS:**

```
var animationDown = function () {
    var arrImages = $('li.image-container').filter(':visible');
    var length = arrImages.length;
    $.each(arrImages, function (i, v) {
        if (i !== length - 1) {
            var nextScale = $(arrImages).eq(i + 1).find('img').css('transform');
            nextScale = decodeMatrix(nextScale, 'scale');
            var nextMargin = $(arrImages).eq(i + 1).find('img').css('margin-top');
            $(arrImages).eq(i).find('img').animate({
                'margin-top': nextMargin
            }, {
                step: function (now, fx) {
                    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + nextScale + ')');
                },
                duration: 'fast'
            }, 'linear');
        } else {
            $(arrImages).eq(i).hide();
        }
    });
};
var animationUp = function () {
    var scaleArr = ['0.40', '0.45', '0.50', '0.55', '0.60', '0.70', '0.80', '0.90', '1.00', '1.10', '1.20'];
    var marginArr = ['-155px', '-140px', '-120px', '-100px', '-80px', '-40px', '1px', '50px', '100px', '200px', '700px'];
    var visible = $('li.image-container').filter(':visible');
    var visibleLength = visible.length;
    var total = $('li.image-container');
    var totalLength = total.length;
    var i, currentMargin, currentScale, currentIndexS, currentIndexM, prevScale, prevMargin;
    var lastVisible = $('li.image-container').eq(0);
    for (i = visibleLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentMargin = $(total).eq(i).find('img').css('margin-top');
        currentScale = $(total).eq(i).find('img').css('transform');
        currentScale = parseFloat(decodeMatrix(currentScale, 'scale')).toFixed(2);
        currentIndexS = $.inArray(currentScale, scaleArr);
        currentIndexM = $.inArray(currentMargin, marginArr);
        prevScale = parseFloat(scaleArr[currentIndexS - 1]).toFixed(2);
        prevMargin = marginArr[currentIndexM - 1];
        console.log('li:' + i + 'currentMargin and currentScale:' + currentScale + ' ' + currentMargin + 'going to get applied property:' + prevScale + ' ' + prevMargin);
        $(total).eq(i).find('img').animate({
            'margin-top': prevMargin
        }, {
            step: function (now, fx) {
                $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + prevScale + ')');
            },
            duration: 'fast',
            complete: function () {
            }
        }, 'linear');
    }
};

function decodeMatrix(matrix, query) {
    var values = matrix.split('(')[1];
    values = values.split(')')[0];
    values = values.split(',');
    var output = {
        a: values[0],
        b: values[1],
        c: values[2],
        d: values[3],
        x: values[4],
        y: values[5]
    };
    output.a = parseFloat(output.a);
    output.b = parseFloat(output.b);
    output.scale = parseFloat(output.a).toFixed(2);
    output.sin = output.b / output.scale;
    output.angle = Math.round(Math.asin(output.sin) * (180 / Math.PI));
    if (query) {
        return output[query];
    }
    return output;
}

$('.content').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
        console.log('down');
        animationDown();
    } else {
        console.log('up');
        animationUp();
    }
    //prevent page fom scrolling
    return false;
});
```

Here is the JS Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/e1p0hkvd/)

Comment: Curious, why are you using predefined `scale` & `margin-top` values for `animationUp` function and not doing the same for `animationDown` method?

Comment: Hi Tahir, thanks for looking at it. I have sort of 10 slots where the images will be placed and the images who are yet to come in that 10 slots will be having the smallest scale and margin top and the images which was on the last slot will have biggest scale and would finally disappear. Currently I am not having  issue with predefined values but the weird behavior of animate jquery. Please take a look and please help if you could see any issues with the animate?

Comment: I don't see any problem with `animate` function itself because it animates just fine with the values you provided it in the first place. I only am finding it difficult to understand the way `scale` and `margin-top` values are calculated. I am worried that the approach here needs to be simplified or something. Looks way too complicated.